# Assign specific port to RPC server\client

Tags: windows, port, rpc

I am writting a RPC client server application on windows. I have gone through RPC sample programs MS has given. But none of them mention port specifically. This probably because RPC uses dynamic port above 1024. But what if I wanted to assign specific port/port range to *specific* service (my server and client app for example). How can I do that? I can use RPCCFG to assign range but that range will be for all RPC programs (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908472) right? How can I control a single program? I know it's possible because exchange seem to able to do it for Client Access Service?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Answer (score 0):

You can define ports in the code or use a config file which you read in the code.

```
   status = RpcServerUseProtseqEp(
  (char *)"ncacn_ip_tcp",            // Use TCP/IP
  RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,    // Backlog queue length for TCP/IP.
  (char *)"4747",                    // TCP/IP port to use.
  NULL); // No security.
```

Success. Jasper